# Angular Renderer2 listen - cannot attach to touchstart and mousedown

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, renderer

I am trying to create a listener on a component attached to either mousedown (for desktops) and touchstart (for mobile)

```
this.renderer.listen(this.el.nativeElement, 'mousedown touchstart', (event: any) => {}
```

However, when I run it like above it doesn't work. When I have 1 option (either mousedown or touchstart) it working fine for given event type, however as soon as I add the second option it doesn't react at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not supported via `Renderer2`. See: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12751

Use this:

```
Observable.merge(
  Observable.fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'mousedown'),
  Observable.fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'touchstart')
)
```